# Make this code non blocking

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-multiprocessing

I'm using the VSphere API, here are the lines that I'm dealing with:

```
    task = vm.PowerOff()
    while task.info.state not in [vim.TaskInfo.State.success, vim.TaskInfo.State.error]:
        time.sleep(1)
        log.info("task {} is running".format(task))
    log.ingo("task {} is done".format(task))
```

The problem here is that this blocks the execution completely whilst the task is not finished. I would like the logging part to be ran "in parallel", so I can start other tasks.

I thought about creating a function that would accept a task as parameter, and poll the `info.state` attribute just like now, but how do I make this non blocking ?

EDIT: I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You could use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and create an event loop. You can use `asyncio.async()` to create an asynchronous task that won't block the event loop execution.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I ommited to say I'm in Python 2.7, I'm editing my post :)

Comment: Ok, in that case, you can use python's threading module. Create a worker to do this task and then join() the worker when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using the threading module:

```
import threading

class VMShutdownThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, vm):
        self.vm = vm
    def run(self):
        task = vm.PowerOff()
        while task.info.state not in [vim.TaskInfo.State.success, vim.TaskInfo.State.error]:
            time.sleep(1)
            log.info("task {} is running".format(task))
        log.info("task {} is done".format(task))

vm_shutdown_thread = VMShutdownThread(vm)

vm_shutdown_thread.start()
```

If you create a [logger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), you can configure it to print the thread name.

Comment: Also, make sure you look into thread safety if you plan on using a lot of threads. For example, consider the scenario when two threads are trying to do stuff to the same object.